# Multiple event listeners in Next.js router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently `next/router` exposes a singleton API where listening to its changes can be done via:

```
Router.onRouteChangeStart = myHandler // subscribe

Router.onRouteChangeStart = null // unsubscribe
```

This poses several architecture-related challenges as two unrelated components can't listen to route state changes at the same time.

Based on the discussion on https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2033 there is no plan to convert `next/router` to an Event Emitter / Observable.

Given that, how can we implement a router with shared subscriptions in Next.js?

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've been happy with so far involves wrapping `next/router` listener methods in Observables and creating a HLA attaching router events to components on componentDidMount.

An example implementation using RxJS:

```
// I'm using recompose for and rxjs, but you should be able to modify this code easily


// 1. sharedRouter.js
import Router from 'next/router'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'


export const routeChangeStart$ = Observable.create(
    obs => {
        console.log('route: start')
        Router.onRouteChangeStart = url => {
            obs.next(url)
        }
    }
).share() // note the .share() operator,
          // it ensures that we don't reassign Router.onRouteChangeStart
          // every time a new component subscribes to this observable

export const routeChangeComplete$ = Observable.create(
    obs => {
        Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
            console.log('route: complete')
            obs.next()
        }
    }
).share()

export const routeChangeError$ = Observable.create(
    obs => {
        Router.onRouteChangeError = () => {
            console.log('route: error')
            obs.next()
        }
    }
).share()

// 2. appBar/withRouterEvents.js
// This one is attached to our AppNav component
import { lifecycle } from 'recompose'
import * as SharedRouter from './sharedRouter'

const withRouterEvents = lifecycle({
    componentDidMount(){
        const onStartLoadingSub = Router.routeChangeStart$
            .subscribe(
                () => {
                    // hide nav
                    // show loading indicator
                }
            )

        const onFinishLoadingSub = Router
            .routeChangeError$
            .merge(Router.routeChangeComplete$)
            .subscribe(
                () => {
                    // hide loading indicator
                }
            )

        this.subs = [
            onStartLoadingSub,
            onFinishLoadingSub
        ]
    },

    componentWillUnmount(){
        if(!Array.isArray(this.subs)) return;
        this.subs.forEach(
            sub => sub.unsubscribe()
        )
    }

})


// 3. appBar/index.js
export default ({
    isNavVisible,
    isLoading,
    children
}) => <nav className={
    isNavVisible ? 'app-bar' : 'app-bar app-bar--hidden'
}>  
    <LoadingIndicator isActive={isLoading} />
    {children}
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Good news! As from Version of Next.js `6.1.1` multiple router event listeners will be allowed:

#### Example

```
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
  console.log('App is changing to: ', url)
})
```

#### Docs

- [Pull Request](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/pull/4726)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#router-events)

Comment: How would you provide a listener attached to a specific route change, as in: After this specific route transition completes, do something?

Comment: `Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
  if (url === 'myURL') {
    // Do something
  }
})`

Comment: How would that work for disabling the subscription? Say I have a global subscription for all route changes, and I want only turn off a single subscription.

Comment: Oh don't use router events for those tasks! Use `componentDidMount`/`componentWillUnmount` for subscriptions.

Comment: Hmm, my use case is for showing an error popup from a parent component. Would this make sense: https://gist.github.com/avremel/23c07962b79bac7aff5d4b3950d0172c